# How can I send emails from the command line with recipient tab-completion and proper file attachment?

Tags: linux, email, bash, attachment, mutt

A year ago I tried a couple of different email senders because I wanted to simplify sending emails from the command line. There are a couple of tools for it, I tried (I don't remember exactly):

- `sendmail`
- `mail`
- `xmail`
- `ssmtp`
- `uuencode`
- some mime scripts I found on the web using `mail`, that handle attachments.
- `echo body text | mutt -s subject -a /etc/resolv.conf [other files] -- test@example.com`

The issue of attaching a file was difficult, due to

- encoding issues
- mime types for binary files
- attaching multiple files failed (no clear boundaries between them)
- send text files as attachment, not in email body

but eventually it worked with `mutt` (with the command above). I would have preferred a method without the invocation of a big program, but I was fine with it.

At some point I stopped using it, because I always had to enter the email addresses by hand and I never remember them.

In order further facilitate command line sending,

> is there an easy way to enable tab-completion for email addresses?

I guess there is some manual work involved, because I didn't find anything on the web. Building an email index (exported cvs from *gmail*) seems easy, but what if *John Jerry* uses `jj44@example.com` as his email address? It would be necessary to complete

- *Jo*`<tab>`
- *Je*`<tab>`
- *ex*`<tab>` and
- *jj*`<tab>`.

This must be somehow fed into the `readline` utility - I don't know if that's difficult, but I'm looking for an easy way, if there is one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [bash-completion package](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#completion) and some custom scripting. Mutt completion is enabled by default.

See the following tutorials for extending the bash-completion functionality:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2